# Bash script to copy files from cd to directory

Tags: bash, if-statement, directory, copy, mount

I have no bash scripting knowledge unforunately. I need a script that reads a cd copied ONE file from the cd to a destination and renames it. Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

mount /dev/cd0 /mnt/

for file in /mnt/*
do
if($file == SO_CV*)
    cp SO_CV* /usr/castle/np_new/CVFULLPC.BIN
else if($file == SO_PC*)
    cp SO_PC* /usr/castle/np_new/PCMAP.BIN
else if($file == MS_PC*)
    cp MS_PC* /usr/castle/np_new/FULLPC.BIN
else if($file == MS_MC*)
        cp MS_MC* /usr/castle/np_new/MBFULLPC.BIN
done

umount /mnt/
```

Could someone tell me if this is even valid bash scripting, or what mistakes I might have made.

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 1):

Syntax problems. Try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

mount /dev/cd0 /mnt/

for file in /mnt/*; do
   if [[ "$file" == SO_CV* ]]; then
      cp SO_CV* /usr/castle/np_new/CVFULLPC.BIN
   elif [[ "$file" == SO_PC* ]]; then
      cp SO_PC* /usr/castle/np_new/PCMAP.BIN
   elif [[ "$file" == MS_PC* ]]; then
      cp MS_PC* /usr/castle/np_new/FULLPC.BIN
   elif [[ "$file" == MS_MC* ]]; then
      cp MS_MC* /usr/castle/np_new/MBFULLPC.BIN
   fi
done

umount /mnt/
```

Comment: The IF test is quite pointless since it copies the matching file(s) anyways.

Comment: @tvm Destination filename is different in each case.

Comment: For the OP: `cp $file ...` would be better, to safeguard against the unexpected condition of multiple files matching the pattern. If you are absolutely sure that exactly one file will match (no more, no less), you could do away with the `if` and just run the 4 `cp` commands.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

error_in_cp () {
   { printf "An ERROR occured while trying to copy: '\s' to its dest file.\n" "$@"
     printf "Maybe there were more than 1 file ? or you didn't have the rights necessary to write the destination?"
     printf "Exiting..."
   } >&2  #to have it on STDERR
   exit 1
}    

mount /dev/cd0 /mnt/ &&
for file in /mnt/*; do
   case "$file" in
     SO_CV*) cp -p SO_CV* /usr/castle/np_new/CVFULLPC.BIN || error_in_cp "$file" ;;
     SO_PC*) cp -p SO_PC* /usr/castle/np_new/PCMAP.BIN    || error_in_cp "$file" ;;
     MS_PC*) cp -p MS_PC* /usr/castle/np_new/FULLPC.BIN   || error_in_cp "$file" ;;
     MS_MC*) cp -p MS_MC* /usr/castle/np_new/MBFULLPC.BIN || error_in_cp "$file" ;;
     *)      echo "oops, forgot to handle that case: '$file' . ABORTING. "
             exit 1
             ;;
   esac
done   # no "&&" here so you always umount /mnt/ even if you aborted the copy or the latest command went wrong
umount /mnt/
```

note: I changed the "cp" to "cp -p" to prevere rights & times... adjust if needed.

note that "&&" at the end of the line is ok
(no need to :

```
 command && \
     something
```

)

You may need to add `{` and `}` around each part if there is more than 1 element (here, "case ... esac" is one element, so it's fine)